# Plugin to easy show divs and parts of website when scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, easing

I asked a similar question a while ago and I've tried a plugin to show divs and elements  when scrolling, but I'm not satisfied with the results.

Now I found this page: http://stacks.co/ that's using an awesome plugin for making elements on the side visible very smooth.

I can't seem to find the plugin for this in the head of the side.

Which plugin is used on this site?

I found that on every element there's a class something like: `<h2 class="fadeIn animated">`

Comment: I guess [THIS](http://stacks.co/js/landing.js) file has the animations

Comment: Is there a specific plugin for this? or is this just made by the developer.

Comment: Well since there's no licence description in plugin, i guess it's done by the developer.

Comment: Allright. Do you know a plugin who could do this? otherwise I have to code this myself. That could be an option, but I don't have much time for that.

Comment: Well i cant give you any advice other than the things i could find with a google search by _jquery page scroller plugin_

Comment: Well. I found a site with exactly the same code http://www.maximsiebert.com/ This should be a plugin.